# Google OpenId and Google APIs

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid

I was trying to achieve an openID login with google and then get an acces token to access google apis (such google plus, or drive)

The first attemp was successful but with a big problem:

- Make the openId stuff, and the user is redirected to google to identify himself, then return to my app identified.
- Make the oAuth stuff with google apis, redirect the user again to identify himself and cameback with a code, then exchange the code for the access token needed to call google apis.

The user needs to identify twice. That's not good.

I read and tryed the [google hybrid openId and oAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#oauth). All links there points to the deprecated oAuth1 interface, and i cant make it work, i get the user identified but not request_token to continue the oAuth stuff.

So i have a couple of questions:

- Is there a way to identify the user agains google openId and at the same time get the users consent to access google apis?
- Is the hybrid protocol still working with oAuth2 and new google apis?
- I'm on the good way or im missing something?

I need both openId and oAuth beacouse the application needs to be in the google marketplace and is a must to login users with openId, and i need to hit some APIs that need oAuth2 access_token.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally i have a working solution, and this is the "magic" url that make the trick for me:

```
String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"
  + "client_id="+ GoogleapiAuthHelper.CLIENT_ID +"&"
  + "response_type=code&"
  + "scope=openid%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me&"
  + "redirect_uri="+GoogleapiAuthHelper.REDIRECT_URI+ "&"
  + "state=security_token%3Dasdalskjqwo91231029";

if( userService.getCurrentUser() != null ){
   url += "&login_hint=" + userService.getCurrentUser().getEmail(); 
}
```

Steps:

- First of all, identify the user with openId, the users go to login screen and type his credentials.
- User return idenfied to the application
- Redirect the user to the URL above. The param login_hint makes that the user dosen't need to idenfity again and the response to this url is a redirection with an oAuth code, wich you can easily exchange for the desirec access token.

After reading all Google Plus API, Google Drive API, oAuth2 and openId documentation, the doc that point me to the rigth direction was https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login?hl=es

I don't know if this is the best way to achieve openId + oAuth, but it works and i cant make it work in any other way. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to work on both OpenID and OAuth side by side, and have two login screens? **If you simply use OAuth 2.0 workflow, the user needs to key in his credentials just once and you can do anything that you want to.**

Once the user consents to the login/permissions screen in the OAuth workflow, your app will get an access token. If you need any client info for, say, a welcome user screen - you just need to hit the https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo endpoint with the access token and it will give you the user's public information. So, in short you can do pretty much most of the things with the OAuth flow, and with the user logging in just once.

Good luck! Feel free to follow up with more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need openId becouse is a must if you want the application in the Google Marketplace, and i want it, so the users must be idenfied with openId. And i need oAuth2 becouse i want to hit the Google Plus API

Comment: Thats what I said buddy, user's can be identified with OAuth too. Why not use it? Once you have got the token - hit the endpoint that I mentioned that would help identify the user.

Comment: Yes users can be identified with oAuth too. Maybe im not understanding [google docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/sso) when saying things like: OpenID Single Sign-On (SSO) must be used in all installable Apps Marketplace applications to provide a seamless login experience.

Comment: I just noticed that in the market application i have some oAuth info, like consumer key and secret and the application is linked to a Console API aproject. Do you know if enabling the APIs in this proyect give me access to the API without extra redirections?

Comment: Yes! If you enable APIs in the console project ,basically your app registers for a scope. With the token your app can hit only those APIs that you are registered for .

Comment: OK perfect. Is strange becouse you can define some scopes in the app manifest for the market, but gPlus or gDrive are not in the whitelist. Adding them in the console API instead of the app manifest do not show them in the allowed scopes for the application in the overview screen, so i assume that when domain admins install the application they are not going to be prompted to consent access to gPlus or gDrive APIs and therefore they are not going to be accesible without extra redirections.